# Why is text appearing in my shiny app when using html tags and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, bootstrap-4, shinyjs

Below is a minimal example of my error:

```
library(shiny)

run_with_enter <- '
$(function() {
var $els = $("[data-proxy-click]");
$.each(
$els,
function(idx, el) {
var $el = $(el);
var $proxy = $("#" + $el.data("proxyClick"));
$el.keydown(function (e) {
if (e.keyCode == 13) {
$proxy.click();
}
});
}
);
});
'

ui1 <- function(){
  tagList(
    div(id = "login",
        fluidPage(
          textInput("uid", "Username"),
          tagAppendAttributes(
            passwordInput("pwd", "Password"),
            `data-proxy-click` = "Login"
          ),
          br(),
          actionButton("Login", "Log in", class = "btn-success"),
          htmlOutput("login_attempt")
          )),
    tags$style(type="text/css", "#login {font-size:10px;   text-align: left;position:absolute;top: 40%;left: 50%;margin-top: -100px;margin-left: -150px;}")
  )}

ui = (htmlOutput("page"))




server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$Login, {
    cat("Login attempted \n")
  })

  output$page <- renderUI({
    div(class="outer",do.call(bootstrapPage,c(tags$br(tags$script(HTML(run_with_enter))),ui1())))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

When the app is run, in the top-left the text "br" appears, but everything else seems to function normally. I've isolated the problem down to the code snippet:
`tags$br(tags$script(HTML(run_with_enter))`

But I'm not sure how to resolve this problem. I can change the "br" tag to any valid HTML tag (e.g. "head") and the text in the top-left is replaced with the new tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than

```
c(tags$br(tags$script(HTML(run_with_enter))), ui1())
```

you should have

```
list(tags$br(tags$script(HTML(run_with_enter))), ui1())
```

The `c()` function strips away attributes from objects which is not what you want in this case. Compare `tags$br()` and `c(tags$br())`

Comment: Great, thanks. I knew that about `c()` not sure why I didn't see that!